# Clear textfield on button click action in Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

I have a number of buttons, that when clicked on will run a script and if successful will generate a Passed/Failed message displayed in a text field on a GUI using Swing. I have noticed that the text for the previous result is still displayed even after clicking on a new button to run a script. This text is displayed until the script has completed, generating a new result which is then displayed.

I would like to add some code so that when a new button is clicked the text field is reset and no text is displayed until the script has completed.

A button:

```
    Test1 = new JButton("Test1");
    Test1.setLocation(290, 30);
    Test1.setSize(120, 30);
    Test1.addActionListener(this);
    Test1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            if (Test1.isEnabled()) {
                errorLabel.setText("");
                result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Test1.class);
                errorMessageDisplay(result);
            }
        }
    });
    buttonPanel.add(Test1);
```

The code for the error message:

```
public void errorMessageDisplay(Result resultPass) {
    errorLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
            errorLabel.setText("");
            errorLabel.setVisible(true);
        }
    });


    if (result.getFailureCount() > 0) {
        errorLabel.setForeground(Color.red);
        errorLabel.setVisible(true);
        errorLabel.setText(" Failed");
    }

    else {
        errorLabel.setForeground(Color.green);
        errorLabel.setText(" Passed");
        errorLabel.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to run your tests on a different thread, you're blocking the gui thread (EDT). Also, why are you creating a listener each time errorMessageDisplay is called?

Comment: The thing is, I want to be able to run only 1 test at a time. Do I not need to create a new lisener then?

Comment: I don't know why you need a new listener, it looks like this one only clears the text, and sets the label visible. It should already be visible if you clicked on it. You are just accumulating listeners that would do the same thing.

Comment: It doesn't clear the text though

Comment: *"Clear textfield on button click action in JSwing"* There is no `J` before Swing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution is to create another thread.

```
if (Test1.isEnabled()) {
    errorLabel.setText("");
    new Thread(()->{
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Test1.class);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->errorMessageDisplay(result));
    }).start();
}
```

That is not a very good solution, look into using a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) or an ExecutorService.

A quick example of using an executor service would be to create an executor when you start.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
```

Then submit jobs to it.

```
if (Test1.isEnabled()) {
    errorLabel.setText("");
    service.submit(()->{
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Test1.class);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->errorMessageDisplay(result));
    });
}
```

This would allow you to submit more than one job, but they would be run serially. You can control the job flow through the gui too.

```
if (Test1.isEnabled()) {
    test1.setEnabled(false);
    errorLabel.setText("");
    service.submit(()->{
        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(Test1.class);
        EventQueue.invokeLater(()->{
            errorMessageDisplay(result);
            test1.setEnabled(true);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: If I create another thread will this mean you can run multiple tests in parallel?

Comment: Yes, you could run multiple things in parallel. If that is your goal, I would definitely suggest looking into an executor service. So you can control how they are executed better.

Comment: I cannot run things in parallel unfortunately hmmm

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. JUnitCore might not let you run tests in parallel. Or it might have it's own mechanism.

Comment: I mean my requirements do not permit tests to be run in parallel. One test must be run after the other

Comment: Edit: This is working great! The only issue with it, is it won't let me execute the same button twice. Do you happen to know why that it is?

Comment: Rather than queue the tests, is it possible to disable the other buttons on the GUI until the test has been completed?

Comment: That is what I did with the third example. You can disable as many buttons as you like.

Comment: I am using the third example but it does not disable the other buttons, I can click the other buttons and it is queuing the tests

Comment: I don't see any other buttons. You have to explicitly call `otherButton.setEnabled(false);` There are some tricks you can do. Such as keep a list of Buttons that you enable/disable all of them. Or descend through the swing hierarchy and disable things, buttons and such.